# Drag and drop function automatically changing value

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I am new for drag and drop functionality. Here is may app link in codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/myzVxq

This is how it works,

1. `data-appt` in `drop` class is used to specify number of `.drag` placed in it. Only two `.drag` can be placed in a `.drop` class.
2. `data-appt` in `drag` class is used to specify height of `.drag` class based on 'td'.
3. `data-appt` value of `drop` class will be changed when drag and drop a 'drag' class of `div`.

Here is my problem,

1. when I drag and drop a `.three` class of `div` its `data-appt` value is change to 1. I don't know why but It should not be changed. And I marked the place where the problem exist with help of comment in javascript code.

Please help me, it will be very helpful for me . Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want it to change, then remove the lines in function **startDrag**:

```
dataAppt = $(this).parent();
dataValue = $(this).attr("data-appt");
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yyReqd

Comment: NO, its not like that. I want to change the `data-appt` attribute value of `.drop` class but `data-appt` of `.drag` class is changing automatically. Please help me to find the error.

Comment: Please show an example of how you want to change it. What value do you want to bet?

Comment: Its more like google calender but i want to place only two appointment per timeslot.